# In "Cursed" what is the location of this castle?

Tags: behind-the-scenes, cursed

When Merlin and Nimue first meet it is in the remains of a ruined castle, is this a real castle somewhere or was it a set/CGI?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Atlas of Wonders has a write up on the filmin locations in *Cursed*: [Filming Locations Guide: Where was Cursed filmed? The Castle Location](https://www.atlasofwonders.com/2020/07/cursed-filming-locations-castle.html). For the most part is seems extremely accurate, here is what it has to say on the location where Nimue and Merlin meet:

> [image: Collage of the exterior and interior of the castle where the characters meet: the top shows the exterior; a ruined castle on a grassy landscape surrounded by forest, the outer walls are almost completely crumbled with the inner towers mostly standing with the attaching walls fallen down. The bottom shows Merlin and Nimue circling each other inside with the latter holding her sword; the ruined building is a circular room with arches on each "edge" overgrown with bushes]
>
> The ruined castle where Nimue meets Merlin in episode 6 pictured above doesn't exist in the real world. Most of the scenes set here were shot in the romantic remains of Waverley Abbey in Farnham, Surrey. Abandoned since the 16th-century, this is a great location for productions set in a medieval world like Cursed.

The interior arches seen above certainly do match Waverley Abbey as seen from [English Heritage's page on the place](https://www.english-heritage.org.uk/visit/places/waverley-abbey/):

[image: Shot of the inside of Waverly Abbey showing the matching arches to the film set running the length of the rectangular building. More ruins can be seen off to the left of the main building]

However, barring the taller part of the building, the exterior certainly isn't a match and appears to be CGI:

[image: The exterior of the abbey, showing a small rectangular stone building with large windows running it's length; at the back of the building a section juts out from the top with windows set into it]

Comment: Ahh, that pesky Henry VIII, making all sorts of picturesque ruins for us.